# Memory Leak Issue on android.content.res.Resources

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have out of memory issue in my app , I have used MAT for the issue. Below are the 3 leak suspects.

Leak Suspect - Dominator tree

[image]

**Problem Suspect 1**
The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "", occupies 9,109,536 (24.42%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.util.LongSparseArray[]" loaded by "".
Keywords
android.util.LongSparseArray[]
android.content.res.Resources
Details »

**Problem Suspect 2**
75,254 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "" occupy 6,816,088 (18.27%) bytes. 
Keywords
java.lang.String
Details »

**Problem Suspect 3**
215 instances of "android.graphics.NinePatch", loaded by "" occupy 6,032,168 (16.17%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by ""
Keywords
java.lang.Object[]
android.graphics.NinePatch**

Details »

Can someone help me out the 1st leak?

and I'm not able to understand the suspect 3 as i"m not using NinePatch images in my project.